# How to render/preview bootstrap elements within TinyMCE-5?

Tags: bootstrap-4, tinymce, tinymce-5

TinyMCE-5 has a very nice feature to preview the content before save.

But even after adding the bootstrap.css to the init function some elements are still not displaying correctly.

```
content_css: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Buttons are fine but tabs, navs and panel don't.